# Replace zener diode of 14v with two in series of 6.8v in power supply board of kenwood kr9940-9040 receiver board shorted

Tags: voltage, diodes, zener

[image]

I am trying to repair a Kenwood quad receiver KR9940.

This receiver has been given to me, hoping that I could give it a new life.
It didn't power on, after first inspection I found a group of four power transistors (it sports eight transistors) NEC 2SD287 faulty which I replaced with four MJ15015 also the four matching wire wound 0.47 resistors where broken in half, and in the power supply board the two transistors 2SC1000 (QK2-QK3) faulty plus one other resistor and zener diode dk1, which I replaced with onother zener of unknown specifications (silly of me).

After this first intervention I powered it up and the fuse R2 of 2 A blown plus the zener shorted and transistor QK2 broken.
The Zener diode (DK1) YZ140 is of 14 V 500 mW as I could not find the exact one I used a 13 V instead.
Previously I replaced the following faulty transistors QK1 2SC789, QK2 and QK3 2SC1000 with QK1 BD243c and QK2 Qkr with BC550 and BC 414.
When I powered up the receiver  smoke came from QK2 and  the zener diode was shorted again.
Is it possible that 1V for the Zener diode made the difference and blew the transistor?
Also in this case as I cannot find the 14 V Zener diode could I possibly replaced it with two in series of 6.8 V each?
I apologise for my knowledge of electronics which is basic level hopefully someone can help, I really appreciate it.
Many thanks.
PS I checked the four power transistors which I replaced and they are still ok.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Question on the repair of equipment not demonstrating an actual *understanding* of the circuit are not on topic.  Likely the actual issue is either misconnection of one of the replacement parts, or an original failure of something else not yet replaced.  At this point you may well be into a situation of cascading damage and should probably seek guidance from someone specifically familiar with these as they appear to still have value in certain circles.

Comment: Wall of text! But your question if you can replace a 14 V diode with two series connected 6.8 V ones - most likely yes.

Comment: thanks for the answer